# How to PayPal DigitalGoods Expresscheckout Setup

Tags: paypal-sandbox

My core requirement is to setup sandbox buyer and seller accounts for my company who sells **DIGITAL GOODS** (software). 
For this anyhow I was able to create sandbox account by first registering on live paypal.com site.

1. The login created with live site does confirms given email id and gives API credentials. Thats ok.
2. But the login created with sandbox site never gives API credentials. Everytime, before giving me API access, it asks to confirm given id - **TO WHICH SANDBOX SERVER NEVER SENDS CONFIRMATION MAIL**. I have tried with many different accounts on different mail providers, but no luck.
3. Without api credentials, signature and all that crap, how can I test my code. - LIVE LOGIN'S CREDENTIALS returns error.
4. So If anybody has faced such problem and resolved it then please post the solution.
5. Also it would be a great help if you provide a complete list of things (dummy buyer/serller account, api credentials etc etc) which I should have before I initiate the first API call to PayPal.

> Apart from this, it is observed that if you are working in sandbox site (sandbox.paypal.com), the url in browser would change anytime to live site (paypal.com, cgi.paypal.com/..., etc) So it creates enough hell like experience that you never know when you are landed when you look upwards in the addressbar. There is a whole list of defects noted but it can be altogether different thread.

Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: What is the e-mail address to your sandbox seller account? I can manually verify it if necessary and ensure Digital Goods is enabled on it.